# Do a third of Italian men live with their parents?

Tags: sociology, culture, italy

I have heard that Italian men live with their parents as a racial stereotype joke and from some Italian friends. They say that this is true because they have seen these people in their environments or neighborhood. But really I want to know if there are trustworthy statistics to prove this famous claim.

Here is [**another one**](http://www.marketplace.org/topics/business/why-italian-men-wont-leave-nest) who has asked the question in an interview:

> **Scott Jagow: In Italy, men stay at home. And by that, I mean they live with their parents. A third of Italian men over 30 still live with mama and papa.**
>
> **The country's economic minister wants them out of the house. He's proposing a $1,500 tax break for young Italians who rent. But he's taking some serious heat for calling these men "big babies."**

Scott Jaglow claims that it is true that many Italian men live with their parents but without giving any exact statistics unless saying "a third"! Is there any research to prove this statistics?

Comment: Wikipedia article on this phenomenon in Japan, Italy and other places: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasite_single

Comment: If you think it can answer the question please send it.

Comment: I've edited to make the question gender neutral (as the quote is also gender neutral).

Comment: Sorry I can;t accept your edit because I want to know about men not both sexes. The question is not gender neutral but the answer is. I want to know if there are more men who live with their parents than women.

Comment: Your quote is inconsistent with your question, providing proof on notability is on your shoulders. Not that it makes a difference, because the answer is well known and it doesn't change.

Comment: @PersianCat, If you want separate info on the sexes, point it as an "extra" question, not the main question. The source and claim are gender neutral, so should be the question.

Comment: The provided link for notability asks "Is it true that most Italian **men** live with their parents until they're 30?" The *answer* provided is gender-neutral, but it shows notability for the question. I, for one, have never heard such a claim, so I shall be editing out the bit that suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Oddthinking I changed the source of news to fit the claim!.. Really it was hard to choose the best between more than 10000 case about this question! It seems to be a very popular question.

Comment: Your claim sais third, but your question asks about most, which means more than half. It would be better if you revise the question to say "more than in other countries" to correlate with the claim.

Comment: I can edit it to be a better fit but not such radical change that you suggest because it will not fit the claim in the source.

Comment: I note a subtle difference between "men over 30" and "until they're 30", but I suspect any answer will cover both.

Comment: So what do you suggest to write instead of it? Do you think it is better to remove the age?

Comment: AFAIK, this is also quite typical in Spain. And Persian Cat is right, it's not a gender neutral thing, it's mostly men.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - "Parasite single"? I guess an embittered parent wrotte that one :)

Answer (score 2):

**The claim is false, because it underestimates the number!**

From 25-34 years of age the percent of men living at home with their parents it's not a third, it's nearly 60%:

[image: Yes]
<sub>Source: [Eurostat Data Explorer](http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=ilc_lvps08&lang=en). Note: I moved the *Sex* combo-box from its original position to be able to crop the image slightly better.</sub>

---

<sub>(slightly)</sub> **More details**

The above screenshot is taken from [Eurostat Data Explorer](http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=ilc_lvps08&lang=en). [Eurostat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/data/database) is the source for most of the official European statistics. Data Explorer is the web interface you can use to browse them; I took the screenshot by focusing on males from 25 to 34, but you can do whatever analysis you like.

This is the only statistic I've been able to find. It focuses on ages from 18 to 34 and the highest range it allows to select it is "from 25 to 34", so technically speaking I'm not exactly answering the question.

The Eurostat data should have been gathered by [Eurofound](http://www.eurofound.europa.eu/). Maybe someone will be more lucky (or patient ;-) ) than me and will find something more suitable on their site.